# How to run promise array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, promise

In this function, callback is called before inline array is completed. How I can call it only when inline has all values?

```
function inlineSearch( search, callback ) {
    const inline = []

    mal.quickSearch( search ).then( response => {
        response.anime.forEach( anime => {
            anime.fetch( ).then( json => {
                inline.push( replyInline( json ) )
            })
        })
        .then( callback( inline ) )
    } )
}
```

`response.anime` is a json object array that point to another json object, that's why I need to fetch it so I can have the correct json.

And, `replyInline` is a function that only takes the json and returns another.

`mal` = My Anime List API

Comment: Have you looked at [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: You need `Promise.all` together with `repsonse.anime.map`

Comment: by the way, the last `.then` is guaranteed to be wrong, since `.then` expects a function as an argument

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried but didn't work it

Comment: no you didn't try, because your code doesn't use it

Comment: @JaromandaX why map and not forEach?

Comment: @JaromandaX my previous code I used Promise.all()

Comment: because using forEach you'd need a var on which to push the promises to use in the `Promise.all` function - the fact that you question using `.map` kinda makes it obvious why your attempt didn't work

Answer (score 2):

use `Array#map` with `Promise.all` - and no need for that `inline` var either

If you *must* use a callback, then the following should work

```
function inlineSearch(search, callback) {
    mal.quickSearch( search )
    .then(response => 
        Promise.all(response.anime.map(anime => 
            anime.fetch()
            .then(json => replyInline(json))
        ))
    )
    .then(results => callback(results));
}
```

Usage:

```
inlineSearch("whatever", function(results) {
    // do whatever with results
});
```

Alternatively, without a callback the above can be written like this:

```
function inlineSearch(search) {
    // note the return
    return mal.quickSearch( search )
    .then(response => 
        Promise.all(response.anime.map(anime => 
            anime.fetch()
            .then(json => replyInline(json))
        ))
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
inlineSearch("whatever").then(results => {
    // do whatever with results
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated, without the callback the code works great. You helped me out solve one thing that for almost five days I was struggling to understand.